# Struts2 + Classloader Vulnerability + How to reproduce

Tags: security, struts2, classloader

How to reproduce the security issue [CVE-2014-0094](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0094). I googled but couldn't able to find any reference to the same.

Comment: Check this. It doesnt exactly tell about 0094 but 0050 . http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2014/02/cve-2014-0050-exploit-with-boundaries-loops-without-boundaries.html

Comment: Thanks. I did looked and I am able to reproduce 0050 where I can observe the CPU usage goes up and I have to kill the tomcat process. But for CVE: 0094 I didn't observe anything. I like to reproduce CVE: 0094 and apply the patch and verify the same.

Comment: @AshishGupta good link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working.

I have to enable logging (for ognl package) to see the error.

Pass in parameter like **class.classLoader.resource.dircontext.docBase=someText** to the struts2 application.

localhost:8080/sampleApp/showlogin.do?class.classLoader.resource.diretext.docBase=someText

Then in the log I would see something like this.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base base does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

After applying the workaround then I don't see above error in the log.

Reference: 
http://www.brentron.com/safe/web/9248.html
http://isayan.cocolog-nifty.com/diary/2014/04/s2-020.html

Answer (score 0):

To get a better help, I suggest you to follow the guidelines in the official [Struts2 Security Bulletins](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/security-bulletins.html).

1. The bug you are refering to has been reported in [S2-020](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-020.html), and has both a workaround without upgrading, and a patch in Struts 2.3.16.1.
2. **WARNING**: the above patch is not enough, as reported in [S2-021](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-021.html), so there are both a new workaround (for users that can't immediately upgrade) and a definitive patch in Struts 2.3.16.2.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, I saw the suggested workaround. But before applying I want to see the impact / effect of the same. I like to reproduce the issue and apply the fix and make sure it didn't happen again. I am looking for a Proof of Concept for this vulnerability which I couldn't able to find any reference in the suggested site.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce the issue just send

```
http://host/struts2-blank/example/X.action?class.classLoader
```

The issue is documented under [S2-020](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-020.html).

Comment: Thanks. What I should observe with above URL (passing in class.classloader as the option). Error in the log file? I didn't get any error everything seems to be fine. I am not sure what I should observe (either in log file / workflow) to see the impact of this vulnerability.