# Jersey REST Webservice is not working in Struts 2

Tags: java, web-services, rest, struts2, jersey

I have created an application Struts2 with Jersey REST webservice, the Struts2 application is working fine but the rest webservice is not working, when execute the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/SAMPLE/resources/users/name/manu
```

I am getting

> There is no Action mapped for namespace /resources/users/name and action name manu. - [unknown location]

Does the version of Struts causes any issues, since I am using Struts 2.1.6 ?

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**`web.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>otims.usermodules.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
             30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> 
  </web-app>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/resources/.*" />
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="com.ocms.app.resources.Resources" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="104857600000" />
    <bean class="otims.usermodules.dao.UserModulesServicesImpl" name="modules"></bean>
    <constant name="struts.serve.static" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.serve.static.browserCache" value="false" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default"  namespace="/">
:
:
:
```

**`UserModulesServices.java`:**

```
package otims.usermodules.services;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/users")
public class UserModulesServices {
    @GET
    @Path("/name/{i}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String userName(@PathParam("i") String i) {
        System.out.println("name::::::::" + i);
        return "{\"name\":\"" + i + "\"}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to change `resources` to some other path.

Comment: @AleksandrM is that causes any problem, i changed but still its not working.....does the version of struts2 causes any issues, since i am using 2.1.6

Comment: `DTD Struts Configuration 2.0` and `struts-2.3.dtd` with `2.1.6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the version of struts2 causes any issues, since i am using **2.1.6** ?

Yes, it does. `excludePattern` [has been introduced in...](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/webxml.html#web.xml-SimpleExample) **2.1.7**.

Please consider upgrading (due to *a lot* of improvement and security fixes) to the [latest Struts version](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi) (**2.3.16.3** today, **2.3.18** soon).

With **2.3.18**, you will also be able to use the new [JakartaStreamMultiPartRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092457/1654265), and try dangerous stuff like setting 100 GigaBytes of Request size as you are doing now :)

Comment: that means i need to use the higher version right, can you tell me which higher version is stable

Comment: Added the link to the latest version

Comment: can i use 2.3.1.2 i guess its a stable version

Comment: Why should you use 2.3.1.2 if the latest one is 2.3.16.3 ? It is stable too, and it has IMPORTANT security bugs fixed. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21603806/1654265 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/23343142/1654265

Comment: You're welcome. Quoting the latest issues from the [Security Bulletins](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/security-bulletins.html): **If you cannot upgrade to version 2.3.16.3 immediately - which is strongly advised...**

Comment: why downloading is getting too slow for 2.3.16.3

Comment: Dunno, try a mirror site :)

Comment: Mmmm... in [the same link](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi), CTRL+F for "mirror" :|