# upgrade from struts 2.1 to struts 2.5 issues

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, expression-evaluation

We are upgrading Struts2 from 2.1 to 2.5, and we migrated all the code from the 2.1 version (which was perfectly working) to the 2.5 version.

We have been resolving several little issues, but one in particular caught my attention. In the old version, we were accessing a value as:

```xml
<s:textfield name = "driverClass.partyDriver[area].info.recordedReason" 
            value = "%{recordedReason}" 
               id = "recordedReason"
/>
```

However, this was not working in our new version. I changed the line above for:

```xml
<s:textfield name = "driverClass.partyDriver[%{area}].info.recordedReason" 
            value = "%{recordedReason}" 
               id = "recordedReason"
/>
```

And this worked perfectly.

Now the problem is that this method is being called in many other jsp files.

My question is:

> is there any way this could be changed by configuration ? Or I basically have to change every line where this is called as in the old version ?
>
> Also, is this issue happening because of the change of version ? Is there any documentation that talks about this changes?

Comment: Which type is `partyDriver` and what is `area`?

Comment: partyDriver is a List<Long, partyObject> and area is of type Long

Comment: it doesn't work due a classloader vulnerability http://stackoverflow.com/a/23344175/573032